# Why Convolution algorithm has not been connected?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

**Describe the problem:**
Error : Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.

**System Information:**
I am working on Spyder in Anaconda.
OS Platform: Windows 10
TensorFlow version: 1.15
Python version: 3.6
Installation command: conda create -n MRI pyrhon=3.6 Tensorflow-gpu
CUDA/cuDNN version: Cudnn- 7.5.0 , CUDA- 10.1
GPU model and memory: GeForce RTX 2060

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?? Why CuDNN is failed to initialize?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your Cuda version is too high, Only TF2.0 and above support 10.1. For lower versions, you need CUDA 10.0. So uninstall 10.1 completely and install CUDA 10.0.

[Cuda 10 for tf 1.13>=](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#install_cuda_with_apt)

[Cuda 10.1 for TF 1.14>=](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements)

Comment: Still same problem happened. after uninstalling cuda 10.1, I rinstall cuda 10.0, cudnn 7.6.4. And to compatible with cuda , visual studio 2017 community version. But still donot work.